# GUI app closes when file explorer is closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI app using Python (3.10) on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3).
The modules used are tkinter (8.6) and python-docx (0.8.11).

The app should allow the user to browse for a .docx file from their PC via a file explorer and then check to see if the document's paper is A4 or not. The check is executed by clicking on the start button. Appropriate messages are printed on the GUI's textbox.

The problem is that once I run the script the app launches along with a file explorer window.
The file explorer should only be opened when the browse button is pressed and I have specified this in my code. If one were to close the file explorer, the whole app is also closed.

I would like to know why such errors occur and how they can be rectified. I have tried to change the position of the open_file function in the code. But this impacts the other function which relies on it and causes errors.

The code is shown below. Any help is welcomed.

```
# import all necessary modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from docx import Document

root = tk.Tk()

# prevent resizing of window
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=300)
canvas.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=3)

# start button specs
start_text = tk.StringVar()
start_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=start_text, command=lambda: paper_size(), font="Arial", bg="light green", fg="black", height=2, width=10)
start_text.set("Start")
start_btn.grid(column=0, row=1)

# user instructions
instructions = tk.Label(root, text="Select a MS Word file", font="Arial")
instructions.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

# clear button specs
clear_text = tk.StringVar()
clear_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=clear_text, command=lambda: text_box.delete(1.0, tk.END), font="Arial", bg="light blue", fg="black", height=2, width=10)
clear_text.set("Clear")
clear_btn.grid(column=2, row=1)

# browse button specs
browse_text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=browse_text, command=lambda: open_file(), font="Arial", bg="orange", fg="black", height=2, width=10)
browse_text.set("Browse")
browse_btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

# text box (output display) specs
text_box = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=50, padx=15, pady=15)
text_box.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
text_box.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
text_box.grid(column=1, row=3)

# Create a File Explorer label
label_file_explorer = tk.Label(root, text="-----", width=100, height=4, fg="blue")
label_file_explorer.grid(column=1, row=1)


# function to open a .docx file using file explorer
def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    file = askopenfile(parent=root, mode='r', title="file explorer", filetypes=[(".docx file", "*.docx")])
    browse_text.set("Browse")
    global filename
    filename = file.name
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="Accessed File: " + filename)
    return filename


# function that checks if the paper size is A4
def paper_size(filename):
    # access file
    doc = Document(filename)
    # check paper size
    paper_hw = []  # store page height and page width
    # loop through all sections
    for section in doc.sections:
        # append page height and page width
        paper_hw.append((section.page_height, section.page_width))  # add dimension tuple

    # execute function to check if page dimensions correspond to A4
    # takes a tuple (width, height) and returns true if it corresponds to A4
    def is_A4(dimensions):
        A4_WIDTH = 7560310  # page width for A4 paper as interpreted by python-docx
        A4_HEIGHT = 10692130  # page height for A4 paper as interpreted by python-docx
        height, width = dimensions  # unpack dimension tuple
        return height == A4_HEIGHT and width == A4_WIDTH

    # obtain number of sections that are not A4 and also convert them into strings
    not_A4 = [str(i + 1) for i, section in enumerate(paper_hw) if not is_A4(section)]

    # check if length of not_A4 and paper_hw are equal. If so, this means all pages are not A4.
    if len(not_A4) == len(paper_hw):
        text_box.insert("end-1c", "All pages are not A4.")

    # check if not_A4 is empty. If so, this means all pages are A4.
    elif len(not_A4) == 0:
        text_box.insert("end-1c", "All pages are A4.")

    # check if not_A4 has one element. If so, this means one section is not A4
    elif len(not_A4) == 1:
        text_box.insert("end-1c", f"Section {not_A4[0]} is not A4.")

    # check if the list not_A4 is not empty and if the length of the list paper_hw is greater than the length of the list not_A4
    # If so, this means multiple sections are not A4
    elif 0 < len(not_A4) < len(paper_hw):
        text_box.insert("end-1c", f"Sections {', '.join(not_A4)} are not A4.")


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=250)
canvas.grid(columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that the line `def paper_size(filename=open_file()):` will execute `open_file()` immediately.

Comment: @acw1668 I see. I used that line to use the file name returned from the open_file function for the paper_size function. Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I have tried to store the value of file.name in a variable called filename in open_file() and then return that variable. This variable is then used as the input to the paper_size function by the following code: def paper_size(filename):

This approach gives me an error which states:
TypeError: paper_size() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

The source of this error is from: command=lambda: paper_size()

I have no ideas what this means.

Comment: Note that you execute `paper_size()` (without argument) inside the command lambda, but the definition of `paper_size()` function requires an argument.  For your case, the simple way (but not recommended by others) is using global variable to store the filename.

Comment: I have modified my code to add to suggestion. But I get a warning that says:
Global variable 'filename' is undefined at the module level. While the paper_size() function associated with the lambda command gets a warning: Parameter 'filename' unfilled. When I run the script the GUI allows to choose a file, but when the start button is pressed this error message is produced: TypeError: paper_size() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Comment: You need to remove the argument `filename` from the definition of `paper_size()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. It works now. Although I still get a warning for the global variable. This states: Global variable 'filename' is undefined at the module level. Is this ok?
Also, would I need to remove filename from the line: doc = Document(filename) ? 
It seem to work fine with and without filename in the brackets.

Comment: As it turns out I do need to include filename in the line: doc = Document(filename). Otherwise the previous file can still be read (without being loaded) if the script is run again.

Comment: I don't get the error *"Global variable 'filename' is undefined at the module level"*.

Comment: Strange. Must be a PyCharm issue. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I run it in both PyCharm (2021.3.3) and terminal without the error.  Both using Python 3.10.4.

Comment: Sorry. I Should clarify. "Global variable 'filename' is undefined at the module level" is not an error, but rather a weak warning in which filename is yellow wavy underlined. Probably not much of an issue. Appreciate your help on the problems.